# batch if exist command

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to save a game and it will just get stuck. When I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> it will leave a blank spot. Does anybody see a mistake in my script here?

```
@echo off
:saveload
title player movement
color 0f
cls
set /a health=10
if exist saves.txt (
    < saves.txt (
        set /p weapon=
        set /p armorh=
        set /p armorc=
        set /p armorl=
        set /p armorf=
        set /p bow=
        set /p gold=
        set /p dmgweapon=
        set /p dmgbow=
        set /p prtah=
        set /p prtac=
        set /p prtal=
        set /p prtaf=
        set /p name=
    )
    goto :varsetup
) else (
    echo to first begin we need to get your name!
    set /p name=What is your name?: 
    (
        set /p armorh=n/a
        set /p armorc=n/a
        set /p armorl=n/a
        set /p armorf=n/a
        set /p bow=n/a
        set /p gold=10
        set /p dmgweapon=1
        set /p dmgbow=0
        set /p prtah=0
        set /p prtac=0
        set /p prtal=0
        set /p prtaf=0
        set /p name=%name%
    ) > saves.txt
    goto :saved
)
:saved
```

Comment: hmm it seems to be that my comment does not contain proper code i did include four spaces but it won't work if someone can fix that i'd really appreciate that

Comment: You need a blank line between normal text and the code block. Anyway, in your `else` branch after `set /p name=`, instead of `set /p foo=bar` you need to state `echo bar`, as far as I got your intention; `if exist` should not be the problem here...

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` branch after `set /p name=`, instead of `set /p foo=bar` you need to state `echo bar`, as far as I got your intention. `if exist` should not be the problem here. Here is the fixed code:

```bat
@echo off
:saveload
title player movement
color 0f
cls
set /a health=10
if exist "saves.txt" (
    < "saves.txt" (
        set /p weapon=
        set /p armorh=
        set /p armorc=
        set /p armorl=
        set /p armorf=
        set /p bow=
        set /p gold=
        set /p dmgweapon=
        set /p dmgbow=
        set /p prtah=
        set /p prtac=
        set /p prtal=
        set /p prtaf=
        set /p name=
    )
    goto :varsetup
) else (
    echo to first begin we need to get your name!
    set /p name=What is your name?: 
    (
        echo n/a
        echo n/a
        echo n/a
        echo n/a
        echo n/a
        echo 10
        echo 1
        echo 0
        echo 0
        echo 0
        echo 0
        echo 0
        echo %name%
    ) > "saves.txt"
    goto :saved
)
:saved
```